# Incorrect prediction using LSTM many-to-one architecture

Tags: python, keras, lstm

I'm predicting 12 months of data based on a sequence of 12 months.  The architecture I'm using is a many-to-one LSTM, where the ouput is a vector of 12 values.  The problem is that the predictions of the model are way out-of-line with the expected - the values in the time series are around 0.96, whereas the predictions are in the 0.08 - 0.12 range.

After generating the 72 random values, I use the function subsequences to create overlapping sequences 12 timesteps long.  So my X dimensions are # of 12-timestep sequences, 12, 1.

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import LSTM
from keras.layers import Dense
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

def subsequences(ts, window):
    shape = (ts.size - window + 1, window)
    strides = ts.strides * 2
    return np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(ts, shape=shape, strides=strides)

test_arr = np.random.normal(0.975, 0.008, size=72)

ts = 12

temp = subsequences(test_arr, ts)
X = temp.reshape(temp.shape[0], temp.shape[1], 1)
y = subsequences(pd.Series(test_arr).shift(-ts).to_numpy(), ts)

X_predict = X[-ts, :, :]

# Lop off the timestamps that have missing values
X = X[:(X.shape[0] - ts - 1), :, :]
y = y[:(y.shape[0] - ts - 1), :]

output = 12

model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(12, return_sequences=True, input_shape=(ts, 1)))
model.add(LSTM(12))
model.add(Dense(output))
model.compile(loss='mae', optimizer='adam')
model.summary()

model.fit(X, y, batch_size = 24, epochs = 50)

yhat = model.predict(X_predict, verbose=0)
```

These are some of the predictions I get:

```
array([[0.11727975, 0.08559777, 0.09116013, 0.09350648, 0.13221847,
        0.08328149, 0.12618074, 0.12006135, 0.11579201, 0.10330589,
        0.11863852, 0.13914064],
       [0.1172842 , 0.08561642, 0.091188  , 0.0935307 , 0.1322322 ,
        0.08330169, 0.12619175, 0.12007872, 0.11579723, 0.10331573,
        0.11865252, 0.13916571],
       [0.11731011, 0.08572483, 0.09135018, 0.09367174, 0.13231221,
        0.08341929, 0.12625587, 0.12017974, 0.1158275 , 0.10337301,
        0.11873408, 0.13931161],
```

If I increase epochs to 1000, the value range does increase, but the maximum is still low - 0.20.